# AWS Lambda - Copy EC2 Snapshot automatically between regions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'd like to create a Lambda function (python) that will copy an already created snapshot to another region, automatically.

I've reached out to AWS Support and they've only sent me GitHub scripts that were for RDS databases. No EC2 snapshot copy scripts :(

Any help would be great!

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This question sounds a bit like you are asking us to write the script for you, or provide you with a third-party resource, which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: I'm fairley new to Lambda and Boto3, but i'm trying to automate copying snapshots from region to region based on CloudWatch Events. 

I currently have code similar to the other answer here, and I'm getting an error message when it runs.

Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': EOL while scanning string literal (lambda_function.py, line 4)

Comment: Then your question should be showing that code and that error message and you should be asking for help with that specific problem. This is a site for help with programming problems, not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that with boto3

`Example:` Copying snapshot from region `us-east-1` to region `eu-west-1`

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    client.copy_snapshot(SourceSnapshotId='snap-xxxxxx',
                         SourceRegion='us-east-1',
                         DestinationRegion='eu-west-1')
```

If the snapshot is encrypted, add `PresignedUrl` parameter additionally.

Comment: Do i need to install boto3 on the server i'm pulling snapshots from? Or does AWS Lambda already have the config files/etc to run this code?

Comment: Lambda is for serverless execution. EBS Snapshots are stored in AWS Space.  No servers are involved here, You just have to add this code in lambda.

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked, 
For configuration i'm using Python 2.7 runtime, Handler = lambda_function.lambda_handler, and my custom IAM role. Thank you for the help.