# Easiest way to retrieve snapshot time stamp and ID from AWS in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to automate passing copies of snapshot backups to different regions using this code ([AWS Lambda - Copy EC2 Snapshot automatically between regions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726536/aws-lambda-copy-ec2-snapshot-automatically-between-regions)).

I have tried using boto3 library in python but I keep getting this error:

```
EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.us-east-1a.amazonaws.com/"
```

Using this code:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')

client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['self'])
```

I have ensured that my config file has the right security keys. Not sure what else I can do to retrieve the pieces of information I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config file was like this:

```
region=us-east-1a
```

changed it to:

```
region=us-east-1
```

works for other regions.`(example region=us-east-2c is region=us-east-1)`