# AWS Lambda - Copy Instance EC2 automatically between regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to automatically copy the Instance EC2 from one region to another using code scripts. I do not know where to start. Please everyone guide me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726536/aws-lambda-copy-ec2-snapshot-automatically-between-regions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Lambda - Copy EC2 Snapshot automatically between regions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41726536/aws-lambda-copy-ec2-snapshot-automatically-between-regions)

Comment: Your title says you wish to copy an AMI, but your question says you want to copy the Virtual Machine. Can you please edit your question to clarify what you wish to do, and what you mean by "automatically"? Thank you.